# how does extern "C" allow C++ code in a C file?

Tags: c++, extern-c

In order to use C++ code in a C file, I read that we can just do `extern "C" { (where the c++ code goes here)}`, but when I try printing something out using cout, I keep getting an error because it does not recognize the library . I think I am just confused on how extern "C" allows you to use C++ code in C.

Answer (score 12):

The opposite is true.  You can use extern C to add code you want to compile as C code using a C++ compiler.

Unless I'm missing something you can't compile C++ code with a C compiler.

Answer (score 10):

The `extern "C"` construct is a C++-specific syntax, no C compiler will understand it.

That's why you will almost always see it paired with some [conditional compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_compilation) like

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
...
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

---

What `extern "C"` *does* is simply to inhibit [*name mangling*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) meaning that symbols defined in a C++ source file can be used in a C program.

This allows you to have a project with mixed C and C++ sources, and the C source can call the C++ functions that have been defined as `extern "C"`.

Very simple, and stupid, example just to show the point:

Lets say we have a C source file, compiled with a C compiler:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(void);  // Declare function prototype, so it can be called

int main(void)
{
    printf("Calling foo...\n");
    foo();
    printf("Done\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Then we have a C++ source file for the `foo` function:

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" void foo()
{
    std::cout << "Hello from foo\n";
}
```

The C source file is compiled with a C compiler, and the C++ source file is compiled with a C++ compiler. Then the two object files are linked together to form the executable program. Because `foo` was defined as `extern "C"` it's symbol name in the object file is not mangled, and the linker can resolve the reference from the object file created by the C compiler.

It works in the other direction as well. Because symbols in C are not mangled the C++ compiler needs to know that, and that is done by declaring the C symbols `extern "C"`, usually in a header file using the conditional compilation as shown above. If `extern "C"` was not used, the C++ compiler would think that the symbols were C++ symbols, and mangle the names leading to linker problems when the linker can't find the mangled symbols.

Equally stupid example: First a C++ source file

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" void bar();  // Declare function prototype as an unmangled symbol

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Calling bar...\n";
    bar();
}
```

Then the C source file

```
#include <stdio.h>

void bar(void)
{
    printf("Inside bar\n");
}
```

Comment: There's a bit more to `extern "C"` than inhibiting name mangling.   It does other things to allow interfacing between C and C++ as well.

Comment: @Peter. What other things (besides overloading)?

Comment: @MadPhysicist - A number of things.  One example is that `extern "C"` functions may use a different calling convention than functions not specified as `extern "C"` - that affects how arguments are actually passed (e.g.  if they are pushed onto the stack, they may be pushed in different order - and therefore need to be retrieved in different order to be used in the function).  Another difference is that anything declared `extern "C"` has external linkage.     There are a few other differences too.

Comment: @Peter. Thanks for the explanation. Does that mean that I can't have extern "C" and meaningfully inline at the same time?

Comment: @MadPhysicist - It depends on what you mean by "meaningfully inline". One purpose of `extern "C"` is allowing C++ code to be called from C via an interface (and vice versa) and that boundary would affect whether either compiler would inline - even if the C and C++ compilers are from the same vendor, even more so if from different vendors.

Comment: @Peter. I mean that if I `#include` a C file into my C++ file with inline functions, will they be inlined properly with `extern C` in the C file, or should I omit it and hope the syntax works out?

Comment: @MadPhysicist -   That's up to the implementation (toolchain, etc).  Even when a function is explicitly marked `inline`, it is only a hint according to the standard, so it may not be inlined at all.  Conversely, most modern implementations happily inline some functions even when not asked to - because they can make a better choice than most programmers.  If the implementation has visibility of the definition (not just a declaration) of an `extern "C"` function, the implementation will decide.

Comment: @Peter. Thanks for the help. It's good to know that I can rely on "normal" inlining behavior even in an `extern "C"` block.

Answer (score 2):

`extern "C"` is a way of putting C code in C++ code. More specifically it tells the compiler to disable certain things like function overloading so that it can also turn off the name mangling. In C++ a simple function like:

```
int add(int a, int b) {
    return a+b;
}
```

Will actually get some funky name in the library to denote the parameters so that if you define another function like:

```
double add(double a, double b) {
    return a+b;
}
```

That it knows which one to call. You don't want that if you're trying to use a C library and that's what `extern "C"` is for. All of this being said, `extern "C"` does not allow C++ in a C program.

Answer (score 1):

Exported C++ symbols, as generated my the compiler, are *mangled* to include additional type information about the symbol to the linker.

So the following overloaded functions would be distinguishable by the linker in C++, but not C:

- `int fn();`
- `int fn(int);`
- `int fn(char*);`
- `int fn(char*) const;`
- `int fn(const char*);`

The **`extern "C" {`** ... **`}`** syntax allows symbols (or references to C symbols) to be defined in C++ code without using the `mangling` rules.
This allows such C++ code to be linked with C libraries.