# Create a C# Wrapper class for the TS3 SDK

Tags: c#, api, sdk, teamspeak

How can I create a wrapper class in C# that basically wraps around the newest version of the TS3 SDK?
(API version 21 - https://www.teamspeak.com/downloads#sdk)

There actually is an existing wrapper, but it's too old. Its TS3 Version 3.0.3...
I have to use 3.1.

Can anyone help me on how to create a wrapper class around a C library?

Thanks.

For clarification:
I can't work with ServerQuery APIs, simply because of the things my program has to do.

Comment: Do [this question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425202/is-it-possible-to-call-a-c-function-from-c-net) seem relevant to your problem?

Comment: That can help me, thanks. But do I have to import the C or the H files?