# Appending external DLL in C to WinForm project in c#

Tags: c#, c++, c, dll, .net-assembly

I have a problem. I have written an external DLL in C but I want to use it in WinForms in C# in Visual Studio 2017. Always I added DLL using "Add reference", but now shows error, something like 'valid assembly or COM'. I added it to my debbag directory and also to project like normall file (add -> existing item). On my computer it works but on others computers shows errors, that exactly this DLL is not detected by compiler or just don`t exists. How can I solve this?
Thanks for help

Comment: A plain C DLL cannot be added "as a reference". You need to use P/Invoke and deploy the DLL (and all of its dependencies) with your project. Why do you have so many language tags on this question?

Comment: you're absolutely going to get downvoted because you didn't bother to search before doing this.  Check out DllImport

Comment: googling 'call c function from c#' first hit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425202/is-it-possible-to-call-a-c-function-from-c-net

Answer (score 1):

DLL written in C cannot add as a reference to C# project. You can [PInvoke](https://moythreads.com/wordpress/2008/02/04/pinvoke-how-to-call-c-from-c/) to call your C DLL.

Here is a good [article](https://www.nag.co.uk/IndustryArticles/Calling_C_Library_DLLs_from_C_sharp.pdf).